# How to do different (custom) scroll-bar in different areas using pure css?

Tags: html, css

The question says it, so is there a way to do different scroll-bar in different areas, for example: have a width of 50px in body and 10px in another div, or do I need to use libraries? I can add additional info if needed.

Comment: of course you can have custom scrollbars on a specific div with only css.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a bootstrap page with the stock scrollbar on the left column and a custom scrollbar for the right column:

[Codeply link](https://www.codeply.com/p/a54Sav0PW0)

html:

```
<div class="container-fluid d-flex flex-column vh-100">

    <nav class="navbar navbar-light bg-light navbar-expand-lg px-0">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">App</a>
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar_links" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>

      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar_links">
        <ul class="navbar-nav">
          <li class="nav-item"><a href="#" class="nav-link">Home</a></li>
          <li class="nav-item"><a href="#" class="nav-link">Link</a></li>
          <li class="nav-item"><a href="#" class="nav-link">Link</a></li>
          <li class="nav-item"><a href="#" class="nav-link">More</a></li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
          <li class="nav-item"><a href="#" class="nav-link">Options</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </nav>

    <div class="row flex-grow-1 overflow-hidden">
      <div class="col-2 mh-100 overflow-auto py-2 d-none d-lg-block">
        <h6>Sidebar</h6>
        <ul class="nav flex-column bg-info rounded">
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link text-white" href="#">Link</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link text-white" href="#">Link</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link text-white" href="#">Link</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link text-white" href="#">Link</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link text-white" href="#">Link</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link text-white" href="#">Link</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link text-white" href="#">Link</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link text-white" href="#">Link</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link text-white" href="#">Link</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link text-white" href="#">Link</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link text-white" href="#">Link</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link text-white" href="#">Link</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link text-white" href="#">Link</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link text-white" href="#">Link</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link text-white" href="#">Link</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link text-white" href="#">Link</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link text-white" href="#">Link</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link text-white" href="#">Link</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link text-white" href="#">Link</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link text-white" href="#">Link</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link text-white" href="#">Link</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link text-white" href="#">Link</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link text-white" href="#">Link</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="col mh-100 scrollbar overflow-auto">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col">
            <h3>Body content</h3>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row flex-grow-1">
          <div class="col mh-100 py-2">
            <p>Ethical Kickstarter PBR asymmetrical lo-fi. Dreamcatcher street art Carles, stumptown gluten-free Kickstarter artisan Wes Anderson wolf pug. Godard sustainable you probably haven't heard of them, vegan farm-to-table Williamsburg slow-carb
              readymade disrupt deep v. Meggings seitan Wes Anderson semiotics, cliche American Apparel whatever. Helvetica cray plaid, vegan brunch Banksy leggings +1 direct trade. Wayfarers codeply PBR selfies. Banh mi McSweeney's Shoreditch selfies,
              forage fingerstache food truck occupy YOLO Pitchfork fixie iPhone fanny pack art party Portland.</p>
            <p>Ethical Kickstarter PBR asymmetrical lo-fi. Dreamcatcher street art Carles, stumptown gluten-free Kickstarter artisan Wes Anderson wolf pug. Godard sustainable you probably haven't heard of them, vegan farm-to-table Williamsburg slow-carb
              readymade disrupt deep v. Meggings seitan Wes Anderson semiotics, cliche American Apparel whatever. Helvetica cray plaid, vegan brunch Banksy leggings +1 direct trade. Wayfarers codeply PBR selfies. Banh mi McSweeney's Shoreditch selfies,
              forage fingerstache food truck occupy YOLO Pitchfork fixie iPhone fanny pack art party Portland.</p>
            <p>Ethical Kickstarter PBR asymmetrical lo-fi. Dreamcatcher street art Carles, stumptown gluten-free Kickstarter artisan Wes Anderson wolf pug. Godard sustainable you probably haven't heard of them, vegan farm-to-table Williamsburg slow-carb
              readymade disrupt deep v. Meggings seitan Wes Anderson semiotics, cliche American Apparel whatever. Helvetica cray plaid, vegan brunch Banksy leggings +1 direct trade. Wayfarers codeply PBR selfies. Banh mi McSweeney's Shoreditch selfies,
              forage fingerstache food truck occupy YOLO Pitchfork fixie iPhone fanny pack art party Portland.</p>
            <p>Ethical Kickstarter PBR asymmetrical lo-fi. Dreamcatcher street art Carles, stumptown gluten-free Kickstarter artisan Wes Anderson wolf pug. Godard sustainable you probably haven't heard of them, vegan farm-to-table Williamsburg slow-carb
              readymade disrupt deep v. Meggings seitan Wes Anderson semiotics, cliche American Apparel whatever. Helvetica cray plaid, vegan brunch Banksy leggings +1 direct trade. Wayfarers codeply PBR selfies. Banh mi McSweeney's Shoreditch selfies,
              forage fingerstache food truck occupy YOLO Pitchfork fixie iPhone fanny pack art party Portland.</p>
            <p>Ethical Kickstarter PBR asymmetrical lo-fi. Dreamcatcher street art Carles, stumptown gluten-free Kickstarter artisan Wes Anderson wolf pug. Godard sustainable you probably haven't heard of them, vegan farm-to-table Williamsburg slow-carb
              readymade disrupt deep v. Meggings seitan Wes Anderson semiotics, cliche American Apparel whatever. Helvetica cray plaid, vegan brunch Banksy leggings +1 direct trade. Wayfarers codeply PBR selfies. Banh mi McSweeney's Shoreditch selfies,
              forage fingerstache food truck occupy YOLO Pitchfork fixie iPhone fanny pack art party Portland.</p>
            <p>Ethical Kickstarter PBR asymmetrical lo-fi. Dreamcatcher street art Carles, stumptown gluten-free Kickstarter artisan Wes Anderson wolf pug. Godard sustainable you probably haven't heard of them, vegan farm-to-table Williamsburg slow-carb
              readymade disrupt deep v. Meggings seitan Wes Anderson semiotics, cliche American Apparel whatever. Helvetica cray plaid, vegan brunch Banksy leggings +1 direct trade. Wayfarers codeply PBR selfies. Banh mi McSweeney's Shoreditch selfies,
              forage fingerstache food truck occupy YOLO Pitchfork fixie iPhone fanny pack art party Portland.</p>
            <p>Ethical Kickstarter PBR asymmetrical lo-fi. Dreamcatcher street art Carles, stumptown gluten-free Kickstarter artisan Wes Anderson wolf pug. Godard sustainable you probably haven't heard of them, vegan farm-to-table Williamsburg slow-carb
              readymade disrupt deep v. Meggings seitan Wes Anderson semiotics, cliche American Apparel whatever. Helvetica cray plaid, vegan brunch Banksy leggings +1 direct trade. Wayfarers codeply PBR selfies. Banh mi McSweeney's Shoreditch selfies,
              forage fingerstache food truck occupy YOLO Pitchfork fixie iPhone fanny pack art party Portland.</p>
            <p>Ethical Kickstarter PBR asymmetrical lo-fi. Dreamcatcher street art Carles, stumptown gluten-free Kickstarter artisan Wes Anderson wolf pug. Godard sustainable you probably haven't heard of them, vegan farm-to-table Williamsburg slow-carb
              readymade disrupt deep v. Meggings seitan Wes Anderson semiotics, cliche American Apparel whatever. Helvetica cray plaid, vegan brunch Banksy leggings +1 direct trade. Wayfarers codeply PBR selfies. Banh mi McSweeney's Shoreditch selfies,
              forage fingerstache food truck occupy YOLO Pitchfork fixie iPhone fanny pack art party Portland.</p>
            <p>Ethical Kickstarter PBR asymmetrical lo-fi. Dreamcatcher street art Carles, stumptown gluten-free Kickstarter artisan Wes Anderson wolf pug. Godard sustainable you probably haven't heard of them, vegan farm-to-table Williamsburg slow-carb
              readymade disrupt deep v. Meggings seitan Wes Anderson semiotics, cliche American Apparel whatever. Helvetica cray plaid, vegan brunch Banksy leggings +1 direct trade. Wayfarers codeply PBR selfies. Banh mi McSweeney's Shoreditch selfies,
              forage fingerstache food truck occupy YOLO Pitchfork fixie iPhone fanny pack art party Portland.</p>
            <div class="footer-spacer"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-12 col-lg-10 offset-lg-2 fixed-right message-box py-2">
        <div class="input-group ">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="" aria-label="Example text with button addon" aria-describedby="button-addon1">
          <div class="input-group-append">
            <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary" type="button" id="button-addon1">Send</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

CSS:

```
div.scrollbar::-webkit-scrollbar {
      width: 1.333333%;
      background-color: rgba(240, 240, 240);
    }
    div.scrollbar::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
      background-color: rgba(193, 193, 193);
    }
    div.scrollbar::-webkit-scrollbar-button:single-button {
  background-color: #bbbbbb;
  display: block;
  border-style: solid;
  height: 13px;
  width: 16px;
}
/* Up */
div.scrollbar::-webkit-scrollbar-button:single-button:vertical:decrement {
  border-width: 0 8px 8px 8px;
  border-color: transparent transparent #555555 transparent;
      background-color: rgba(240, 240, 240);
}

div.scrollbar::-webkit-scrollbar-button:single-button:vertical:decrement:hover {
  border-color: transparent transparent #777777 transparent;
      background-color: rgba(193, 193, 193);
}
/* Down */
div.scrollbar::-webkit-scrollbar-button:single-button:vertical:increment {
  border-width: 8px 8px 0 8px;
  border-color: #555555 transparent transparent transparent;
      background-color: rgba(240, 240, 240);
}

div.scrollbar::-webkit-scrollbar-button:vertical:single-button:increment:hover {
  border-color: #777777 transparent transparent transparent;
      background-color: rgba(193, 193, 193);
}
    .fixed-right {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 1.33333%;
  width: 82%;
  background: white;
}

.footer-spacer {
  height: 74px;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 991px) {
  .fixed-right {
    width: 98.66667%;
      margin-right: 1.333333%
  }
}
```